# jsfiddle top.location.* does not seem to work (while window.location.*) does

Tags: jsfiddle

Is there something with top.location.protocol/host/pathname that makes it not work in JSFiddle?

http://jsfiddle.net/c1of3wfy/

```
alert(window.location.host + window.location.pathname);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hrcsku2t/

```
alert(top.location.host + top.location.pathname);
```

Answer (score 0):

Results panel is on a different domain for security reasons. For the same reason you cannot access a lot of `top.location` properties.

Comment: Is there a way to get around this?  Or will I basically need to debug and build up my code somewhere else?

Comment: This is how secure browsers work. You can't just access a parent frame that's on a different domain name ...